# If module $M = N + mM$, then why is $m(M/N) = M/N$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

I am having difficulty in understanding the proof of Corollary 3 on Pg. 44 of Miles Reid's Undergraduate Commutative Algebra

> **Corollary 3** Let $(A,m)$ be a local ring, $M$ an $A$-module, and $N \subset M$ a submodule; suppose that $M/N$ is finite over $A$, and that $M = N+mM$; then $N = M$.
>
> *Proof* Since $m(M/N)$ = $M/N$, ...

Taking quotient by $N$ on both sides in $M = N+mM$, we get $M/N = (N+mM)/N = mM/(N \cap mM)$, but I can't see how this is $m(M/N)$. Maybe I am missing something easy here, but could someone elaborate on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether $M=N+mM$ or not, it is always true that for any  ideal $I$, we have 
$$I(M/N)\simeq(IM+N)/N$$
the homomorphism being given by
$$\sum_i a_i(m_i+N)\longmapsto\Bigl(\sum_i a_im_i\Bigl)+N$$
One can easily check it is well-defined and bijective.

Comment: Well I actually wanted a clarification on this itself. How does $\sum a_i(m_i+N) = 0$ in $I(M/N)$ imply $\sum a_i m_i \in N$?

Comment: $\sum_i a_i(m_i+N)=0$ means $\sum_i a_i(m_i+N)=N$ really.

Comment: Okay. I was thinking that the $0$ in $I(M/N)$ is $IN$. Instead of looking at $I(M/N)$ as a module on its own, I should just consider it as a submodule of $M/N$, and then their $0$'s coincide, is that right?

Comment: Yes. $IN$  is the $0$ of $IM/IN$, which is a different module.